# Java String.replace not working

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my code.

```
String x = "1+&radic;10";
x = x.replace(".*", "x");
System.out.println(x);
```

This should return `"x"` but istead it is returning `"1+&radic;10"`. Why isn't this working?

Comment: This should return "x" - No, no ".*" found in the String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String#replace` doesn't support regex, use `String#replaceAll`:

```
x = x.replaceAll(".+", "x");
```

Comment: See updated answer, you need `.+` instead of `.*` since `.*` matches twice once for empty string and once for full string.